# What to do when erase fails to delete the element pointed to by the iterator?

Tags: c++, list, erase

In the following code, I try to erase a specific element of templist. However, only the last element of the list is removed. How do I erase that specific element?

```
for(index1 = templist.begin(); index1 != templist.end();)
{
    checkit=templist.end();
    --checkit;

    if((*index1).origin == (*udit).dest && sumweight + (*index1).weight <= 25000)
    {
        sumhr += 1 + (*udit).hr;
        sumweight = sumweight + (*index1).weight;
        stops++;

        tour.at(i).push_back((*index1));

        if(index1! = checkit)
            index1 = templist.erase(index1);
        else
        {
            templist.erase(index1);
            index1 = templist.end();
        }
    }
    else
        index1++;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is and what your code does (or is supposed to do). Could you reduce your code to just enough complexity as to illustrate your problem?

Comment: This: `templist.erase(index1); if(index1!=checkit)` is bad, you just erased it! then this: `index1++;` you increment `index1` in the for loop deceleration and in the loop itself, do you intend to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> What to do when erase fails to delete the element pointed to by the iterator?

Not sure how you concluded that. Some data supporting that claim would have been useful.

However, your use of iterators is a little buggy. You are incrementing the iterator twice after you erase an element.

A suggested fix:

```
for(index1=templist.begin(); index1!=templist.end(); /* Don't increment the iterator here */ ) 
{
   if((*index1).origin==(*udit).dest && sumweight + (*index1).weight <=25000)
   {
      sumhr+=1+(*udit).hr;                         
      sumweight=sumweight+(*index1).weight;
      stops++;

      tour.at(i).push_back((*index1));

      // Erase the item and get the next iterator.
      index1 = templist.erase(index1);
   }
   else
   {
      // Increment the iterator only when we are not erasing.
      ++index1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that after you erase the element from the container the iterator is invalid. To fix this you just need to change your logic a little bit. Since the `erase` function returns an iterator that references the next element in the container you can use that to your advantage. How exactly you do this in your project is up to you but it should work like the following

```
if (index1 != checkit)
{
    // Remove the item. The iterator returned by "erase" is the next one
    // in line so there's no need to manually advance to the iterator with ++
    index1 = templist.erase(index1);
}
else
{
    // Remove the item and skip to the end.
    templist.erase(index1);
    index1 = templist.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i implemented these changes but still only manage to erase the last element. I further uploaded the whole program, maybe the flaw is in there.