# Keeping values of vector

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with writing a program to keep only duplicates,here is what I already wrote :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    for (int n; std::cin >> n;) 
    {v.push_back(n); }
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator b = v.begin();b<v.end();++b)
    {

        if(*b != *(b+1) )
        {
            v.erase(b);


        }

    }

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();i < v.end();++i)
    {
        std::cout<<*i<<" ";
    }


}
```

What I mean by "keep duplicates" is  for example
`Input: 13 7 2 13 5 2 1 13` 
`Output : 2 13` 
I apologise if code is not so perfect, I'm complete beginner.I hope you understand my  dificulties.

Comment: Classic case of iterator invalidation. Best thing to do is to work from the end of the vector to the start.

Comment: What you mean, to  switch begin and end ?

Comment: Dude, what do you think happens to the remaining elements after the one you take out? They all shift back one place. So `++b` is going to do nasty things.

Comment: That's why im asking you guys to help me out , I have no clue what I should do next and I'm stuck for like 3 hours with this problem

Comment: You need to get your debugger out and see things for yourself. 3 hours is nothing. 3 years is a doctorate.

Comment: You can use reverse_iterators, you can read about this here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator. That is for going through the vector "from the end to the start"

Comment: The answers to the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441512/what-to-do-when-erase-fails-to-delete-the-element-pointed-to-by-the-iterator might be useful.

Comment: What about something like [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to remove entries you don't want?

Comment: @Theooc try using this instead of the loop in which you're erasing elements. `auto last = v.begin();
 for (auto b = v.begin(); b < v.end() - 1; ++b)
  if (*b == *(b + 1) && (*b == *last || *b != *(last - 1)))
   *last++ = *b;
 v.erase(last, v.end());` [Here is full code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JJyDlcP74rCD8WP4).

Answer (score 0):

When you `erase()` from a `vector` all iterators pointing at the erased element or later in the `vector` becomes invalidated. Fortunately, `erase()` returns an iterator to the element that was after the erased element, so you could do:

```
for(auto b = v.begin(), end=std::prev(v.end()); b != end;) {
    if(*b != *(b+1) ) b = v.erase(b);
    else              ++b;
}
```

Note that you need to stop iterating one element *before* `end()` since you do `*(b+1)`.

The above does however not remove *all but one* of the repeated elements.

A different approach could be to search for the first element not being part of a repeating sequence and to erase the element if it had no repetitions and to erase all repetitions but one if it had repetitions.

I've used the standard algorithm [`std::find_if_not`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) in the example below but you can easily replace it with a loop that does that same thing. Just search for the first element *not* being equal to `*b`.

```
#include <algorithm>

for(auto b = v.begin(); b != v.end();) {

    // find the first element not being a repetition of *b
    auto r = std::find_if_not(b + 1, v.end(), [&b](const auto& v) { return *b==v; });

    if(b + 1 == r) b = v.erase(b);        // *b had no repetitions, erase b
    else           b = v.erase(b + 1, r); // erase all repetitions except one element
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to dereference an invalid iterator. On the last iteration of your second for loop, `*(b+1)` will try to dereference this iterator. 
Change:

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator b = v.begin();b<v.end();++b)
```

to:

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator b = v.begin();b<v.end()-1;++b)
```

And change your erase to:

```
v.erase(b+1)
```

You are trying to erase the iterator in the current iteration.

Comment: Any comment on the `v.erase(b);` that happens in the loop?

Comment: If you're gonna point this out, you should probably suggest using a range based for loop.

Comment: `<` for iterators is pretty unusual

Comment: I might doing it wrong , but still there's a issue with this algorithm